# regexMatcher for URL with query parameters in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How should I use parameters like this in `regexMatcher` in Spring Security? I have many URLs that start with `/sUrl` and have different parameters. This code doesn't work!

```java
.regexMatchers("\\/sUrl\\?params=\\{url:\"reports\\/Manager\",subSystem:\"ABS\"\\}").access("hasRole('ROLE_ABS')")
```

Controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "sUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView sUrl(@RequestParam(name = "params") String params) {
            RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
        .
        .
        .
            return redirectView;
}
```

URL seen in network partition of browser inspector when I click on this link:

> sUrl?params={url:%22reports/Manager%22,subSystem:%22ABS%22}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a regular expression with the [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) query parameter, see [`RegexRequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RegexRequestMatcher.html):

> Uses a regular expression to decide whether a supplied the URL of a supplied `HttpServletRequest`. Can also be configured to match a specific HTTP method. The match is performed against the `servletPath` + `pathInfo` + `queryString` of the request and is case-sensitive by default. Case-insensitive matching can be used by using the constructor which takes the `caseInsensitive` argument.

and [`HttpServletRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString()):

> Returns the query string that is contained in the request URL after the path. This method returns `null` if the URL does not have a query string. Same as the value of the CGI variable QUERY_STRING.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> a `String` containing the query string or `null` if the URL contains no query string. The value is not decoded by the container.

Your modfified code:

```
.regexMatchers("\\/sUrl\\?params=\\{url:%22reports\\/Manager\%22,subSystem:%22ABS%22\\}").access("hasRole('ROLE_ABS')")
```